# jQuery .animate width not working in IE7/IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, jquery-animate

I am developing a site that has a pop out calculator. On clicking the button 'Quote Calculator' a div animates, first height then width and sits on top of all other elements on the page. This works in IE9, Chrome, FireFox & Safari, unfortunately it refuses to work in IE7/IE8.

When 'Quote Calculator' is clicked it only animates the height and then stops - leaving a thick blue line over the page, it does not animate the width.

I have searched for a similar problem here, and on Google, to no avail.. What is the problem?

Here is my code:

```
$("#calcbutton").click(function () {
    $("#pnecontainer").show();
    $("#pnecontainer").animate({height: "550px", position: "absolute", top: "75px"});
    $("#pnecontainer").animate({width: "925px", left: "-635px"});
});
```

Is there a way to make it work on IE7/IE8 or will I have to settle for something less aestetically pleasing, like a disappearing/reappearing box?

**UPDATE:**

I have implemented the animations all on one line/as part of same function.

Interestingly, for some reason, whilst it won't allow me to implement 2 animations in the same function on first click, it does allow me to do so on the minimize function like so:

```
$("#minimizebutton").click(function () {
    $("#pnecontainer").animate({width: "-925px"});
    $("#pnecontainer").animate({height: "-550px", top: "-635px"});
    $("#pnecontainer").hide(100);
});
```

Odd.. thoughts anyone? (comments only please, answer has been accepted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to be using **callback functions**, waiting to animate the width until the other animation finishes, or maybe just put all the animations in the same `.animate()`

IE7/8 aren't great with JS let alone animations, so the 2 animations on the same item running at the same time are probably what's causing the issue.

```
$("#pnecontainer").animate({height: "550px", position: "absolute", top: "75px"}
    , function () {
         $("#pnecontainer").animate({width: "925px", left: "-635px"});
});
```

Or animate it all in 1 line

```
$("#pnecontainer").animate({height: "550px", position: "absolute", top: "75px", 
                            width: "925px", left: "-635px"});
```

Comment: Thank you, animating all in one line works, it still looks about 70% as good so I'm happy with this fix, also the other two who answered were right about the 'position' property, if I implement the animation all in one line *with* the 'position', nothing happens. So upvote for all and accept for this answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

IE7 does not recognize the property `'position'` in jquery `.animate()`.

Try this :

**CSS**

```
#pnecontainer { position: absolute; }
```

**JS**

```
$("#calcbutton").click(function () {
    $("#pnecontainer").show();
    $("#pnecontainer").animate({height: "550px", top: "75px"});
    $("#pnecontainer").animate({width: "925px", left: "-635px"});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

IE7 browser does not recognize internally the property 'position' and you can't run 2 animations in the same time